# Difference between emberjs and ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

ember-cli adds generators similar for this ones from rails and I would like ask if there are any difference between this two libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Many  differences, even between same named concepts. Rails analogy doesn't help much to learn.

Comment: I mean difference between emberjs and ember-cli rather than ember and rails.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it's a typo in title

Comment: Maybe post isn't enough clear.

Answer (score 7):

Ember cli is a build system / tool belt for use with ember. Ember-cli is the preferred way of working with an Ember application as it introduces standardizations in directory structures and build process.

The documents as of 1.11.x refer to directory structures that Ember-cli will setup for you and keep consistent from project to project and addon to addon.

It provides watching (auto building on change) and live reload capabilities

It has generators as you mentioned which generate test stubs and ensure stuff is in proper folders.

It provides all of the tooling to get started with tests quickly. It sets up test runners and plenty of helpers to make writing tests quick and easy.

It also provides an addon ecosystem which makes addons for ember consistent and easy to produce and consume by all skill levels

Might be best to just peruse the documents and check out all of the capabilities

http://www.ember-cli.com/

Comment: It should be noted that ember-cli is now the preferred way to build emberjs applications. Documentation and instructions on emberjs.com all refers to the ember-cli way of structuring the application as of Ember 1.11.X.

Comment: Thanks petter. Added your commentary as well as a blurb on tests.